# TypeScript not finding style modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following basic configuration in my webpack which is relevant to loading my styles via TypeScript:

```
{
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.s?css$/,
      use: [
        { loader: 'style-loader' },
        {
          loader: 'typings-for-css-modules-loader',
          options: {
            sass: true,
            modules: true,
            camelCase: true,
            importLoaders: 1,
            namedExport: true,
            localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
          }
        },
        { loader: 'sass-loader' },
      ]
    }],
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      app: srcPath,
    },
    modules: ['node_modules', srcPath],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.scss', '.css', '.tsx', '.ts', '.d.ts'],
  },
}
```

In my `tsconfig.json`, I have the following to match:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "app": ["./app"]
    }
  }
}
```

However, I am consistently getting an error when trying to load a file from `app/styles/root.scss`, with the following project structure:

```
├── components
│   └── Root.tsx
├── styles
│   └── root.scss
├── index.hbs
├── index.scss
├── index.scss.d.ts
└── index.tsx
```

[image]

It seems like TypeScript is not able to resolve this path correctly. If this were a plain JS based file, it would work fine.

Strangely, I can add a `root.scss.d.ts` with the defintions for the CSS file and it will resolve correctly. I think this is a bit strange because I am specifically using `typings-for-css-modules-loader` for this task.

How do I get TypeScript to resolve these scss files under the styles directory?

Comment: try '../styles/root.scss'

Answer (score 1):

## Fix

Simply

```
declare module "*.scss";
```

## More

See the JavaScript to TypeScript migration guide : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/migrating.html